# How to improve the efficiency of the standard matrix addition algorithm in c?

Tags: c, performance, matrix

How would I improve the efficiency of the standard matrix addition algorithm?

The matrix is represented by a 2D array and is added sequentially.

Comment: Switch to C++ and use Eigen :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improving the efficiency of Standard Matrix Multiplication Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900711/improving-the-efficiency-of-standard-matrix-multiplication-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to read all your code. As I can see, this is the addition part

```
 for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
    for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
       C[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
```

I don't think this can be improved complexity-wise. As for other types of microoptimizations such as doing a `++i` instead of `i++` or changing the order of the loops etc. - I think you shouldn't care about these until you've run a profiler which shows you that these are your performance bottlenecks. Remember, ***premature optimization is the root of all evil*** :)

Comment: well, you can think about the order of the loops so you don't have to fix it later. shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds. also, the OP asked *specifically* about efficient computation.

Comment: I checked the generated ASM code, i'm not good at reading it but it doesn't look SIMD instructions to me, so with big matrices it is clearly not the best solution.

Comment: @yi_H Perhaps you need a better compiler?!

Comment: Only thing keeping me from giving a +1 is the fact that you mentioned `i++` versus `++i` without stating clearly that this is an optimization myth and it will **never** make any difference to the code generated except when the value of the result is used (and then of course they have different behavior).

Comment: @R.. Most contemporary compilers are lousy at vectorizing any but the simplest C code. I have to spoon-feed GCC intrinsics for basically any matrix operation.

Answer (score 0):

The naive double for loop is pretty close to optimal for portable code, so long as you get your two for loops in the right order.  You need to be accessing the memory sequentially to get best performance.

You could unroll the loops but this won't make very much difference to performance.

If you want best performance then don't write it yourself and instead use a [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) that has been optimised for your platform.

Answer (score -3):

You can try to use GPU instead of CPU for performing intensive operations. You can use AMP for this.

Comment: SSE is on CPU rather than GPU. GPU could be quite fast though, but you don't get at it with SSE.

Comment: true. my bad, AMP is using GPU.

Comment: I have never use-it but should be part of DirectX. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2011/06/15/targeting-heterogeneity-with-c-amp-and-ppl.aspx)