# Improving the efficiency of Standard Matrix Multiplication Algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matrix

How can I improve the efficiency of standard matrix multiplication algorithm?

The main operation involved in this approach is:  `C[i][j]+=A[i][p]*B[p][j]`

What can be done to improve the efficiency of the algorithm?

Comment: @xtremer: What kind of matrix? Square? Almost-square? Power-of-two sides? Tall-and-skinny? Sparse? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at using a BLAS (Basic Linear Algebra Subroutine) library, specifically Intel offer their MKL [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/), AMD have their ACML [here](http://developer.amd.com/libraries/acml/pages/default.aspx) and there's also the (opensource) Goto BLAS [here](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2).

The (dense) matrix-matrix multiply kernel will be a `?GEMM` call, where the `?` indicates the floating point type. For example `DGEMM` will call the `double` routine.

Unless you're extremely confident you know what you're doing with low-level optimisations, these libraries will probably offer better performance than something you can code by hand.

If you do want to have a go at coding this yourself then you may want to consider the following:

1. Use "vector" instructions. `SSE, SSE2..4` instructions are widely supported, some newer `CPU`'s will also support `AVX` instructions.
2. Nested loop unrolling to maximise the ratio of floating point operations to load/store operations.
3. Block-wise algorithms to ensure effective cache use.
4. Multi-threading.

This reference might give you an idea of the current state of things:

> High-performance implementation of the level-3 BLAS - K Goto.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 I've discovered if the matrix is small, DGEMM can blow a large fraction of time checking its character arguments, which are there to make it general purpose. So for small matrices I save a good amount of execution time by doing it the plain-old hand-coded way. Sometimes completely unrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading Chapter 1 of [Golub and Van Loan](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computations-Hopkins-Studies-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/0801854148), which addresses this exact question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cache blocking - making sure you're properly using and reusing values in the cache
2. Better algorithm - the "by-definition" way to multiply matrices is not optimal, take a look at [Strassen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)
3. Parallelization - if your machine has more than one core and/or processor, you can divide and conquer
4. SIMD - take advantage of [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) vector instructions in modern CPU architectures
5. GPGPU - modern GPUs are optimized to do just this sort of thing. Look into [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).

Note that using these methods does not guarantee better performance. There is a lot of tuning required give a significant speedup. There is a lot of money going into figuring out how to multiply matrices quickly so there is no shortage of journal articles on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

If the question concerns multiple matrix multiplications - M1 x M2 x ... x Mn - then there is another optimization technique based on dynamic programming, which is sort of another ball-game. Note that this doesn't apply to improving the efficiency of multiplying two matrices; however, if you are multiplying three or more matrices in a pairwise fashion, then you can optimize at an even higher level. Just thought I'd throw this answer on the heap to round out the information.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's [Strassen's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm), which, depending on the size of your matrix, is ever so slightly faster than the standard algorithm that you listed. There are of course [even faster algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm), but they arent so simple to implement.

The standard algorithm is O(N^3),
Strassen's algo is O(N^2.8),
and Coppersmith-Winograd is O(N^2.3)